# Sending Push Notification from mobile to particular user using parse [Parse IOS]

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, parse-framework

I have saved user pointer in instalation class. Web backend shows 0 subscribers  [image: Response]

I am sending notification using below code

```
 PFQuery *qry = [PFUser query];
        [qry getObjectWithId:friendObject.objectId]; //friend object is ok like @"Fefl5x7nhl"

        PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
        [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:qry];

        // Send push notification to query
        PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
        NSString *msgString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ :%@",
                             [newMessage objectForKey:@"userName"],
                             tfEntry.text];
        [push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
        NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              msgString, @"alert",
                              @"ursound.caf", @"sound",
                              @"Increment", @"badge",
                             // @"Optionally a type was set", @"type",
                              nil];
        [push setData:data];
       [push sendPushInBackground];
```

[image: Installation class]
My installation class does have this user pointer (friend object) and logically it should be  receiver of the notification .

AM i missing something? any suggestion would be great . Thanks for your valuable  time

Comment: pls postyour answer again its working

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a column on the `Installation` class called `user` that is of type `Pointer<My_User>` and you've actually populated it, your code should work.

There's a section in the Push Notification documentation that talks about adding data to the `Installation` class:

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/iOS

Comment: my installation class does have Pointer To user class and i am able to send push notification from mobile. but notifications are not being received (i mean subscriber 0 ) are being shown on parse backend.

Comment: I have edited my question and added detail. Now parse server showing that notification is being sent but 0 subscriber .

Comment: Your `Installation` class "user" column is of type `Pointer<TBUser>` but your query is comparing it to the inbuilt User class, so expecting `Pointer<_User>`.

Comment: Millions of thanks. i have modified  my query and now push notifications are being received correctly .  PFQuery *qry = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TBUser"];
                [qry whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:friendObject.objectId];
                
                PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
                [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:qry];